# Why isn't setState refreshing my screen after deleting from a list of products in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, setstate

Greeting everyone, I have an issue with setState not working in a flutter. The issue might seem with the Dialog not being stateful, but the dialog only returns a ball so it doesn't need to be that way.

The problem that I'm encountering is that I have a list of products that I fetch from the database on display inside of a scaffold. And when I try to delete one of those the screen doesn't refresh even though I call out for the function that sets the list of widgets displayed (and yes it does include setState).

Here is a 10 second demo of the problem:

https://easyupload.io/dg1gy6

And here is the code corresponding to the page:

```
class _ProductManagementState extends State<ProductManagement> {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late List<Map<String,dynamic>> products = [];
  late List<Widget> elements = [];

  List<String> listDynamicToString(List<dynamic> list){
    List<String> listS =[];
    for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){
      listS.add(list[i].toString());
    }
    return listS;
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String barcode)async{
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("UserScans").get();
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> usersScans = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

    for(int i = 0; i<usersScans.length;i++){
      Map<String,dynamic> oldData = usersScans[i];
      oldData.remove(barcode);
      String email = usersScans[i]['email'];
      await firestore.collection("UserScans").doc(email).delete();
      await firestore.collection("UserScans").doc(email).set(oldData);
    }

    await firestore.collection("Products").doc(barcode).delete();

    await setProducts();
    await setElements();
  }

  Future<bool> showDeleteDialog(String barcode) async {
    bool condition = false;
    await showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog( // <-- SEE HERE
              title: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete This product?'),
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      child: const Text('Yes'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        condition =true;
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      child: const Text('No'),
                      onPressed: (){

                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ]
          );
        });
    return condition;
  }

  Future<void> setProducts() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("Products").get();
    products = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  }

  Future<void> setElements()async {
    setState(() {
      elements.add(
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: CircularButton(
              icon: Icons.add,
              bgcolor: Colors.green,
              iconColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){

              }),
        )
      );

      for(int i =0;i<products.length;i++){
        elements.add(
            InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                List<dynamic> ingreidientsD =products[i]['Ingreidients'];
                List<String> ingreidients =listDynamicToString(ingreidientsD);
                List<dynamic> categoriesD =products[i]['Categories'];
                List<String> categories =listDynamicToString(categoriesD);

                Product p = Product(
                    products[i]['Name'],
                    products[i]['Maker'],
                    products[i]['ImageUrl'],
                    products[i]['Details'],
                    '',
                    products[i]['Barcode'],
                    ingreidients,
                    categories,
                    DateTime.now());
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> ProductDetails(Result: p,)));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                    decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 1.5,
                          blurRadius: 1,
                          offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                bool delete = await showDeleteDialog(products[i]['Barcode']);
                                if(delete) {
                                  await deleteProduct(products[i]['Barcode']);
                                  }
                              },
                              style: kWelcomeScreenCircularButtonStyle.copyWith(backgroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red)),
                              child: const Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 20,)
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children:   [
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(products[i]['ImageUrl']),
                                  radius: 70,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 40.0,
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  child: VerticalDivider(
                                    thickness: 3,
                                    color: kCPGreenDark,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children:  [
                                      Text(products[i]['Name'],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Eastman',
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: kCPGreenMid
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      ),
                                      Text('By : ${products[i]['Maker']}',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Eastman',
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            color: kCPGreenMid
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]
                    )
                ),
              ),
            )
        );
        elements.add(const SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ));
      }
    });
  }

  void setEverything()async {
    await setProducts();
    await setElements();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    setEverything();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kCPWhite,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kCPGreenDark,
        title: Text("Product Management",style: kTitleTextStyle2.copyWith(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 24),),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: elements,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone can tell what exactly can i do in order to make it so it does refresh i would be most thankful !

Comment: your super.initState is in the wrong place, although that may not affect the functionality.  Always good to follow the rules though.

Comment: You're calling an async function indirectly from initState.  As initState is synchronous, this will not have the desired effect, and might lead to your behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake here doesn't have to do with set state, the way you're updating your UI every single time is pretty ressource consuming first and not really efficient especially if you make a mistake in the process that you can't see (I can't either honestly). The workaround I'd suggest you though is instead of updating manually the UI with setState whenever you modify something on firestore to use streambuilders instead. It manages itself automatically all you need to do is to make sure to properly interact with firestore and it should update on the UI by itself. I hope this will help, good luck !

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I really appreciate it. Since it's already past midnight where I am right now, I'll try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: this has worked wonderfully ! thank you so much :)